# How to query all articles from a specific user?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

**CODE:**

server-side

```
     /**
     * List of Articles
     */
    exports.list = function (req, res) {
      Article.find({ 'user.displayName': 'GIGANTOR !' }).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(422).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
          });
        } else {
          res.json(articles);
        }
      });
    };
```

---

**SITUATION:**

What I tried above does not work. I checked the mongoose docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

but can't seem to get the query to work. Currently, the query just returns nothing.

---

**QUESTION:**

How to query all articles by a user with a specific `displayName` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR You can't query a document by a field that belongs to a populated object.

Since `article` simply has a `ref` to `User`, you'll have just get all articles, and then filter them in memory. Or, since the `article.user` field is an `_id`, you can find articles by the user ID (but your question is asking about finding them by `user.displayName`).

Mongoose `populate` does *not* do the populating in the MongoDB server itself; it populates on the application server. This means that multiple round-trips to the database are happening (see article [Understanding Mongoose Population](http://frontendcollisionblog.com/mongodb/2016/01/24/mongoose-populate.html).) Therefore, you can't query by a field that exists as part of a populated object.

So, here's your 2 solutions:

```
  Article.find({}).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      let filteredArticles = articles
      .filter(article => article.user.displayName === 'GIGANTOR !');

      res.json(filteredArticles);
    }
  });
```

Or, if you can query by `_id`, you can do this:

```
  Article.find({ user: 'somemongoobjectidofuser' }).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
```

It gets to be a bit hairy and out of scope of the question, but another solution is the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), which is only usually recommended for backend analytics. But, it'll provide you more flexibility in your query (especially if  you user MongoDB's new [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)).

Or, you can always store a copy of the user as a denormalized object inside the article document itself, but then you run into the much-discussed issue of maintaining denormalized documents in-sync.

Comment: Thank you for your complete and well organized answer. About querying all and the filtering on client: wouldn't that be very inefficient ?  On another note: I am using mean.js and just found an interesting piece of code that I added to my question. I am just not sure how to use it for querying or if it can be used at all for querying.

Comment: Nvm, I got it working ! Thank you for providing the correct syntax !

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the code I ended up using here for people who could need it:

```
/**
 * List of Articles
 */
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Article.find({ user: req.user._id.toString() }).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
};
```